# php - How to create path in a portable way using PHP API

Tags: php, path, backslash, slash

### Problem:

Both, `dirname()` and `realpath()` returns a path with the *correct* slashes depending what OS you are running the script.

I want to create a path in a portable way (using PHP API) so I don't have to worried about `\` or `/` slashes.

`realpath()` returns `FALSE` if the path doesn't exist. So, it's not an option to do:

```
define("MY_PATH", realpath(__DIR__."/myNewDirToCreate");
```

In other different case, `dirname()` will not be an option for:

```
define("MY_FILE", "I/should/use/an/abstract/path/definition.file");
```

because it will return the parten directory, not the path to the file. I could handle the problem by myself, using either `regex` or `string` replace. But `PHP` is a cross-platform environment and for sure I'm missing some function in the extensive PHP documentation.

### Question:

- How do I create a path no matter what OS is the script running on **using** `PHP API`, if possible? e.g. `path("no/matter/what/os/are/you/running/this.file\or\what\slashes\you\are\using");`

Comment: You should not care about forward and backward slashes, they will both work. All you have to do is to use dirname() to get the base path, then, from there, just use forward slash everywhere and it will be just fine, i promise :)

Comment: @Twisted1919 you were right. An error in my code misslead me that the error was the mixin of slashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a constant available, it is called `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

```
$path_to_file = $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file
```

It‘s documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php#constant.directory-separator

Be advised that PHP handles this internally, so on Windows you may get a forward slash, but they will work just fine inside PHP!

Comment: Nice info for this constant. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote up my solution on portal paths with PHP. http://webdeveloper.gdemolished.com/php-portal-paths/

Comment: you really like sprintf don't you? @Halfstop

Comment: I guess, it's a useful function. In my example, I'm using it once. @TheSurrican