# correct regex date pattern for dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: php, regex, date

I need to update the same line, which is also including a date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format along with some string, in a group of files. I have checked answers here given to similar questions however couldn’t make any of the patterns suggested run in my code.

My current PHP code is:

```
<?php
// get the system date
$sysdate = date("d/m/Y");
// open the directory
$dir = opendir($argv[1]);
$files = array();
// sorts the files alphabetically
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    $files[] = $file;
}
closedir($dir);
sort($files);
// for each ordered file will run the in the clauses part
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $lines = '';
    //  filename extension is '.hql'
    if (strpos($file,".hql") != false || strpos($file,".HQL") != false)
    {
        $procfile = $argv[1] . '\\' . $file;      
        echo "Converting filename: " . $procfile . "\n";
        $handle = fopen($procfile, "r");
        $lines = fread($handle, filesize($procfile));
        fclose($handle);
        $string = $lines;
        // What are we going to change runs in here
        $pattern = '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]';
        $replacement = $sysdate;
        $lines = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
        echo $lines;
        $newhandle = fopen($procfile, 'w+');
        fwrite($newhandle, $lines);
        fclose($newhandle);
        // DONE
    }
}

closedir($dir);

?>
```

When I run this code on command prompt, it doesn’t give any error message and it seems to be running properly. But once it finishes and I check my files, I see that the content of each file is getting deleted and they all become 0 KB files with nothing in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should surround the regular expression with delimiter character.

For example:

```
$pattern = '![0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]!';
```

`/` is commonly used, but because the regular expression contains `/` itself, I used `!` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You have no delimiters set in place for your regular expression.

A delimiter can be any (`non-alphanumeric`, `non-backslash`, `non-whitespace`) character.

You want to use a delimiter besides `/` so you avoid having to escape `/` already in your pattern.

You could use the following to change your  format:

```
$pattern = '~[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}~';
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/zT4lY0)

Answer (score 1):

This one also do basic checks (month between 1-12, day between 1-31)

```
(0(?!0)|[1-2]|3(?=[0-1]))\d\/(0(?!0)|1(?=[0-2]))\d\/\d{4}
```

See it live: http://regex101.com/r/jG9nD5

Answer (score 0):

Besides the lack of delimiters (# and ~ are favorites, if / is used in the pattern), you are looking for 4 digits at the beginning: yyyy/mm/dd. Decide what you're looking for. You might also be able to do something like

```
[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}
```

or even

```
\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}
```

... I know those will work in Perl, but I haven't tried them with PHP (they ought to work, as the "p" in preg stands for *Perl*, but no guarantees).

Comment: thanks a lot for notifying me that I have been using the pattern in wrong order!

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex? Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class for validation.

```
var_dump(validateDate('2012-02-28', 'Y-m-d')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('28/02/2012', 'd/m/Y')); # true
var_dump(validateDate('30/02/2012', 'd/m/Y')); # false
```

**<kbd>[function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323025/67332)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be rewritten in short like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// get the system date
$sysdate = date('d/m/Y');
// change working directory to the specified one
chdir($argv[1]);
// loop over the *.hql files in sorted order
foreach (glob('*.{hql,HQL}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {
    echo "Converting filename: $argv[1]\\$file\n";
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    $contents = preg_replace('#\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}#', $sysdate, $contents);
    echo $contents;
    file_put_contents($file, $contents);
}
```

The problem was with the missing PCRE regex delimiters as others already pointed out.  Even after fixing this, the code was not really nice.

The `glob` and `file_get_contents` functions are available as of PHP 4.3.0.  The `file_put_contents` function is available as of PHP 5.

[`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) makes your code more succinct, readable and even portable as you won‘t have to mention directory separator anywhere except the info message. You used `\\` but should have used [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17097283/2157640) if you wanted your code to be portable.

The [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function fetches the whole contents of a file as a string. The [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function does the opposite – stores a string in a file. If you want it in PHP 4, use this implementation:

```
if (!function_exists('file_put_contents')):
function file_put_contents($filename, $data) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
    $result = fwrite($handle, $data);
    fclose($handle);
    return $result;
}
endif;
```

Also notice that the final `?>` is not necessary in PHP.

Comment: thanks, I will share it with my colleagues in order them to discuss for a replacement.

Comment: @user3087150 Hope you’ll learn how short your code could be. It is much easier to read and debug then.